# Avoiding trivial MVDs from non-trivial FDs?

Tags: relational-database, relational-algebra

I have two Functional Dependencies from one relation:

```
meetid -> pid
meetid, pid -> status
```

For relation Meetings(meetid,pid,status)

I want to use *promotional* approach to make multivalued dependencies from this. The problem is that I'm not sure if `meetid ->> pid` is legal to do in this situation, as the *complementation* rule will make the other MVD illegal (I think):  `meetid ->> status`.

The other FD will create a dependency that I see as a trivial MVD.

```
meetid,pid ->> status
```

Is this relation doomed to be trivial when promoting them to MVDs, or am I missing something in the process?

Comment: Please post the particular approach version you are following or a reference to it. Since your question involves following it, we should know exactly what you are trying to do. Otherwise we can only hope that your problems are addressed by answering in terms of another version. What do you mean by "make the other MVD illegal"? Why do you think that might be so? Do you think that there is a part of the procedure that talks about "making a MVD illegal"? So why worry about it? Just follow the procedure. If you're not sure of the procedure or how to follow it then show us how you have followed it.

Comment: I actually realized that I used a wrong approach / didn't make the minimal candidate key..

My thoughts on the MVD being illegal was, that meetid's values couldn't determine status'. But with meetid being the only candidate key, this is no longer a problem.

Renzo gave a good clarification/answer detailing what I did wrong in my approach, so I hope that is OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two dependencies:

```
meetid → pid
meetid, pid → status
```

are not minimal, since they can be simplified (for instance by computing a canonical cover) in:

```
meetid → pid
meetid → status
```

and from this we know also that `meetid` is the only candidate key of the relation. From a FD `X → Y` one can always derive the MVD `X →→ Y`, so, you have both the MVD dependencies:

```
meetid →→ pid
meeditd →→ status
```

(Note that the second one can also be derived from the first one by *complementation*).

Note also that none of them is a trivial MVD, since a MVD `X →→ Y` is trivial (that is, always true) if either `Y` is the empty set or `XY` are all the attributes of the relation.

Furthermore, we can note that the schema is in 4NF, since it is in BCNF and each left hand side of non-trivial MVDs is a superkey.

Finally, note that *every* functional dependency can be “promoted” to a multivalued dependency, so that we have also `meetid, pid →→ status` (and *this* is trivial).

Comment: Yeah, I realized shortly after posting that I had the wrong approach to my FDs, and that meetid in fact were the only candidate key. Thanks for the clarification, though!